# How to get the Gwent cards if you missed them in the tutorial

Tags: the-witcher-3

In the tutorial of the game I did not get the Gwent cards and now the innkeeper is not accessible anymore.

Is there any way to get the cards I missed ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this comment on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/witcher/comments/37derb/gwent_strategy_guide/crm7owl), the cards are available from the Shopkeeper you rescue from the Griffon during the tutorial, as of patch v1.04.

Having checked, it seems that that shopkeeper now has the four cards that I'd missed - namely:

- Catapult
- Blue Stripes Commando
- Crinfrid Reavers Dragon Hunter
- Foltest (Lord Commander of the North)

After being rescued, the shopkeeper is located to the west of Woesong Bridge, in White Orchard.

[image: Map Image]

Comment: Where is this Shop Keeper ?

Comment: I've added it to my answer, but just a little west of the Woesong Bridge signpost, in White Orchard.

Comment: Does this include the one you win from the innkeeper?

Comment: Hm. That's a fair point - as there was only four cards in the shop, and I can't remember if I played / beat the innkeeper, I can't confirm this. It might be that one or the other of the shopkeeper / innkeeper didn't have a winnable card, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: Apparently the Leader card was the one you win from her. You wouldn't happen to know how to get the card from the guy during the tutorial mission in the palace?

Comment: Can you travel back to the palace?

Comment: Didn't realize it, but I'm reading that you can go back.

Comment: Yeah, it is one of the areas. Back up one from the qt map (as if going to Skellige) and it's over to the east of Velen.

Answer (score 0):

No, according to the Prima guide there is no way to get cards from the first innkeeper in White Orchard if you missed it. Innkeepers usually have a random assortment of cards, while some have a specific card or two